# Checking internet connection as relentless service in android

Tags: android, internet-connection

I am developing an application, where there is a need to check internet connection availability as a continuous procees as long as the whole application is running and destroy when application is not in use.

The process should notify me, if internet connection is in reach or gone on internet connection availability. On it's notification, I will do some task, both for if not available or available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`BroadCastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for network changes, then use the [`ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) to check if the connection has been lost.

You will need to add these lines in your `AndroidManifest` (replacing `MyClassName` with the name of your class, just as you would do for any `Activity` declared in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyClassName">
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```